# How to extract a list of only parent entities from a nested model?

Tags: django-rest-framework, nested, foreign-keys

I am setting up a catalogue of items for a seller.A seller cab have multiple catalogues. A catalogue can contain multiple items.These items can contain multiple models.

Now based on my URL, I should be able to fetch the list of sellers first to enable the user to select a seller, and then let the user select a catalogue under the seller and so on.

With my current code, whenever I try to fetch the seller list, the list also fetches the entire relationships to the lowest level. The query set I am using seems to be forming the right query.

I tried using the .values,.values_list,.only options. But this gives me error 
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `catalogue` on serializer `SellerDataSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'catalogue'.

My Model is :

```
class SellerData(models.Model):
    seller_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    seller_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller_id

class CatalogueData(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cat_year = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerData,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='catalogue')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_id

class ItemsData(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    catalogue = models.ForeignKey(CatalogueData,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='items')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_id

class ModelsData(models.Model):
    model_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    items = models.ForeignKey(ItemsData,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='models')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_id
```

The Serilizer looks like :

```
class ModelsDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ModelsData
        exclude=('items',)


class ItemsDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounts= ModelsDataSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.ItemsData
        exclude=('CatalogueData_id',)

class CatalogueDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    statements=ItemsDataSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.CatalogueData
        exclude=('customer_id',)


class SellerDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    CatalogueDatas= CatalogueDataSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.SellerData
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # get CatalogueDatas
        catalogues_data = validated_data.pop('catalogues')
        seller = models.SellerData.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for catalogue_data in catalogues_data:
            # get statements data
            items_data = catalogues_data.pop('items')
            catalogue_data['seller_id']=seller
            catalogue=models.CatalogueData.objects.create(**catalogue_data)
            for item_data in items_data:
                models_data = item_data.pop('models')
                item_data['catalogue']=catalogue
                item=models.ItemsData.objects.create(**item_data)
                for model_data in models_data:
                    model_data['items']=item
                    models.ModelsData.objects.create(**model_data)


        return seller
```

my Viewset is written as :

```
serializer_class=serializers.SellerDataSerializer
    queryset=models.SellerData.objects.values_list('seller_id')
```

Expecting to get something like

```
{
   "seller_id":"1",
   "seller_id":"2"

}
```

But I get back

```
{
    "seller_name":"Super Cust",
    "seller_id" :"1234",
    "catalogue":[
        {
                "cat_id":"order-1",
                "cat_name":"furniture",
                "cat_year":"2019",
                "items":[

                        {
                            "item_id":"item_1",
                            "item_name":"sofa",
                            "models":[
                                {   
                                    "model_id":"10001",
                                    "model_name":"White"
                                },
                                {
                                    "model_id":"10002",
                                    "model_name":"Blue"
                                }
                            ]

                        }
                            ]


                        }


                ]


        }
    ]



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happends because you are nesting the serializers. If you want the SellerDataSerializer to only output the sellers ids then delete the nested serializer, for example:

```
class SellerDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.SellerData
        fields = '__all__'
```